# Reshape survey data to get counts of responses in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, reshape2

I have some anonymized survey data:

```
df <- structure(list(User = c("user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5", 
"user6", "user7", "user8", "user9", "user10", "user11", "user12", 
"user13", "user14"), Q1 = c(0, 3, 5, 0, 6, 5, 1, 4, 6, 4, 5, 
0, 0, 0), Q2 = c(0, 6, 4, 0, 4, 5, 0, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 0, 4), Q3 = c(0, 
4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 0, 4, 4, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0), Q4 = c(5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 6L), Q5 = c(7L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
5L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), Q6 = c(6, 5, 7, 7, 7, 
6, 7, 6, 0, 5, 4, 7, 3, 6), Q7 = c(6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L), Q8 = c(1, 4, 6, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 4, 
5, 4, 0, 1, 3), Q9 = c(3, 3, 4, 0, 4, 5, 1, 4, 3, 5, 7, 4, 0, 
0), Q10 = c(3, 3, 3, 0, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 0, 4), Q11 = c(3, 
4, 5, 0, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 6, 4, 0, 0), Q12 = c(6, 6, 5, 0, 4, 
0, 7, 4, 5, 3, 0, 6, 5, 5)), .Names = c("User", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", 
"Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12"), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = "data.frame")
```

The data frame looks like this - the values represent responses on a scale of 1-7:

```
     User Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 Q6 Q7 Q8 Q9 Q10 Q11 Q12
1   user1  0  0  0  5  7  6  6  1  3   3   3   6
2   user2  3  6  4  6  5  5  7  4  3   3   4   6
3   user3  5  4  5  6  6  7  7  6  4   3   5   5
4   user4  0  0  3  7  7  7  7  3  0   0   0   0
5   user5  6  4  4  6  5  7  6  4  4   5   4   4
6   user6  5  5  5  6  5  6  6  6  5   5   5   0
7   user7  1  0  0  6  7  7  7  3  1   3   5   7
8   user8  4  4  4  4  4  6  4  4  4   4   4   4
9   user9  6  6  4  3  4  0  5  4  3   5   3   5
10 user10  4  5  5  4  6  5  6  5  5   6   5   3
11 user11  5  5  5  6  6  4  6  4  7   7   6   0
12 user12  0  5  0  5  6  7  6  0  4   5   4   6
13 user13  0  0  0  3  6  3  7  1  0   0   0   5
14 user14  0  4  0  6  6  6  6  3  0   4   0   5
```

I would like to get counts of responses per question.

In other words, for the result;

- columns would be the 1-7 scale
- rows would be the questions
- values would be the count of responses per question

Essentially, the resulting table would look like this:

```
  Question  count1  count2  count3  count4  count5  count6  count7 
        Q1       1       0       1       2       3       1       0
        Q2       0       0       0       4       4       2       0
        Q3      ....     ....   ....
```

How do I accomplish this in R? Likely using the `reshape2` package I'm guessing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`reshape2` has been replaced mostly by `tidyr`.  Here's a solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(question, response, Q1:Q12) %>% 
  count(question, response) %>% 
  spread(response, n, fill = 0)
```

Results in:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 8
   question   `0`   `1`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`
   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Q1        5.00  1.00  1.00  2.00  3.00  2.00  0   
 2 Q10       2.00  0     4.00  2.00  4.00  1.00  1.00
 3 Q11       3.00  0     2.00  4.00  4.00  1.00  0   
 4 Q12       3.00  0     1.00  2.00  4.00  3.00  1.00
 5 Q2        4.00  0     0     4.00  4.00  2.00  0   
 6 Q3        5.00  0     1.00  4.00  4.00  0     0   
 7 Q4        0     0     2.00  2.00  2.00  7.00  1.00
 8 Q5        0     0     0     2.00  3.00  6.00  3.00
 9 Q6        1.00  0     1.00  1.00  2.00  4.00  5.00
10 Q7        0     0     0     1.00  1.00  7.00  5.00
11 Q8        1.00  2.00  3.00  5.00  1.00  2.00  0   
12 Q9        3.00  1.00  3.00  4.00  2.00  0     1.00
```